# jars, external properties, and external file io

Tags: properties, io, executable-jar

I checked quite a few similar questions, but so far I am unsatisfied with the solutions.

Ever use the Minecraft Server? At initial launch, it creates all the files and folders it needs, and allows you to make changes to files like Server.properties and ops.txt by making them external of the executable jar file.

I'm working on a similar project, and I want to duplicate that behavior. Everything works great when I run it in eclipse. When I export to a jar file though, things get funky. The external files and folders are created without a hitch, but afterword, it would appear as though they cannot be read from or written to. Any ideas how Notch made his server?

--edit-- 
Scratch that, it doesn't even appear to reliably create the files and folders. Maybe it only creates them the very first run after creation?

--edit again--
It creates them in the root directory. When I tested it in eclipse, the root directory was limited to the folder containing the project, and therefore looked fine. The solution was to make the class aware of it's location, and include it in all file operations.

Comment: https://github.com/Bukkit/CraftBukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/net/minecraft/server/PropertyManager.java might help

Comment: this is awesome... let me take a gander...

Comment: I'm sure this is relevant code... I just don't... understand it... I'm sorry. I'm new to the world of java.

Comment: Optionset cannot be resolved to a Type. Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the main class in your executable jar file look up where it is, then have it store that information in a global String or something. Prefix your filenames with that string in your file operations, and voila! It's writing to the correct directory.

Comment: Why, thank you, kind and mysterious sir! Judging by delay in getting that answer, it would appear as though I'd been stuck on it for a while!

Comment: Your very welcome. I hope it helps not only you, but anyone else who has a similar problem!